# Laravel SQL obtaining a group of records using latestOfMany

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm working inside a Laravel 8 application used as a backend to a front-end. I have 3 models:

1. `Domain`
2. `Dns` (linked to `Domain` using `belongsTo`)
3. `DnsCheck` (linked to `Dns` using `belongsTo`)

The general idea is that the `Domain` model holds a website such as example.com, and `Dns` simply contains metadata about how the `DnsCheck`'s should be performed, and, because the number of DNS types per domain is unknown, `DnsCheck` has a `type` column for instance: **a** or **aaaa** as there may be more than one record per domain.

Ultimatly, there could be as many as 15 `DnsCheck` entries, and the `Dns` model contains an `interval` column which dictactes how often the DNS of a domain should be checked, so there could be 13 entries generated every hour for instance.

My issue I'm finding now is I'd like to show the end user all of the latest "checks" performed on their domain's DNS and return it as an array that I can loop over, but to the best of my knowledge, on my `Dns` model the `latestOfMany()` method would simply give me one result?

How can I get the latest records, I have a `checked_at` column on my `DnsCheck` model, I'll attach a screenshot.

#### `Dns` model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dns extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Indicates if the model's ID is auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'dns';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'last_notified_at' => 'datetime',
        'last_checked_at' => 'datetime',
        'disabled_at' => 'datetime',

        // record types that we can monitor
        'a_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'aaaa_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'caa_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'cname_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'mx_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'ns_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'soa_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'srv_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'txt_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'ptr_record_is_enabled' => 'boolean'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the dns checks that this dns has
     */
    public function dns_checks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DnsCheck::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the latest dns check
     */
    public function latest_dns_check()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(DnsCheck::class)->latestOfMany();
    }

    /**
     * Get the domain that owns this dns
     */
    public function domain()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Domain::class);
    }

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleted(function ($model) {
            $model->dns_checks()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

#### `DnsCheck` model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DnsCheck extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'dns_checks';

    /**
     * Get the dns that owns this dns check
     */
    public function certificate()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Dns::class);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, it's a quite easy.
Just order the relation (by id or checked_at, i'm ordering by id):

```
$dns = Dns::with(['dns_checks', => function($q) {
  $q->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}])->find(30); //example

// output example
[
  'id' => 30,
  'a' => 'google.com',
  'dns_checks' => [
    [
      'id' => 4,
      'checked_at' => '2022-07-28 16:46:00',
    ],
    [
      'id' => 3,
      'checked_at' => '2022-07-27 16:46:00',
    ],
  ],
]
```

To Limit the dns_checks, you can do after orderBy the relation a

```
$q->limit(YOURLIMITNUMBER);
```

Comment: not quite, imagine I have 2 checks, 60 minutes apart, first check gives me 10 DNS records and 2 of them are A records, and then second check gives me 20 DNS records, now with 5 A records... I need to obtain the newest checks. I'm wondering that I might need to have some kind of group column with a random uuid at the check interval and also store this on my `Dns` model and update at each check interval... ??

Comment: So you need to create a table dnscheckresult, so for each check you create a single check, then store the check results to another table that references check id to the check created!

Comment: dns -> [ dns_check -> [ result, result ], dns_check -> [ result, result ], dns_check -> [ result, result ], dns_check -> [ result, result ]  ]

Comment: you do not need to create a rondom uuid, just separate the check results from the check itself, then pluck the results that are "a" or "aaaa" from the dnscheck (supposing that you need to show only a or aaaa checks for the final user)